# what's behind the scenes of the return for a method?

Tags: c++

I am studying c++ and my teacher write this code:

> - `Tpoint` and `TObjetGraphique` are two separated classes
> - `origine` is an object of type `Tpoint` declared `private` within `TObjetGraphique`
>
>   ```
>    TPoint TObjetGraphique::getOrigine() const
>       {return (TPoint(origine));}
>   ```

I am wondering why we wouldn't just write:

```
TPoint TObjetGraphique::getOrigine() const
   {return origine;}
```

Is there any difference ?

Comment: You're right, it's pointless.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, I misread the parens, I feel dumb. I'll delete that comment. Sorry/thanks!

Comment: The parentheses around the return value are also pointless. The argument for these in the old days was that putting them in is symmetrical with `if`. The trouble with that, and the counter-argument, is that a `return` isn't an `if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cast in your teachers code is totally pointless

> ```
> TPoint TObjetGraphique::getOrigine() const
>     {return (TPoint(origine));}
>           // ^^^^^^^       ^ You can just omit this as proposed
> ```

assumed that `origine` is of type `TPoint` as stated.

---

If `origine`'s type can be converted to `TPoint` in any way the explicit cast is pointless either.

If there's a reason for that syntax then that `TPoint` has constructor declarations like

```
struct SomethingElse {
    int a_;
    int b_;

    explicit SomethingElse(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
    SomethingElse() = default;
};

class TPoint {
public:
    explicit TPoint(SomethingElse rhs)  : x_(rhs.a_), y_(rhs.b_) {
        std::cout << "TPoint::TPoint(const SomethingElse& rhs)" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int x_;
    int y_;
};

int main() {
    SomethingElse something;
    // TPoint pt1({2,3}); // <<<<<<<<<< Fails
    TPoint pt2(something);
}
```

which looks quite unusual but finally works to prevent `TPoint` being instantiated from `SomethingElse` inadvertently (see the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57df4eb495405db3)).

Comment: Some programmers like to be explicit instead of relying on implicit conversions.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to address this. If implicit conversions aren't wanted that should be expressed in the declaration.

Comment: @Barmar It isn't a conversion, it is a copy construction, and the compiler has to create one anyway, so this makes two, which is pointless.

Comment: I'm not saying they don't want the conversion, they just want to express it explicitly in the code for clarity.

Comment: @Barmar And my point is to express that at the declaration of that interface as much as possible.

Comment: @Barmar And the compiler still has to do another one, so there are now two copy constructions. It is pointless. It also *lacks* clarity, as does any redundant syntax.

Comment: @EJP I thought it would elide the redundant one. If not, then it definitely is inappropriate.

Comment: @Barmar It might. It is pointless to write extra code, and it is pointless to rely on compiler optimisations that might not occur, and it is pointless to spell out what the compiler already has to do. And it still isn't a conversion.

Answer (score 3):

If `origine` is a `TPoint` there is no difference.

If `origine` is not a `TPoint` then it will invoke either an operator `TPoint` of whatever `origine` is or `TPoint::TPoint(<whatever origne is>)`